# How to rename files using a list file?

Tags: powershell, rename

I have 100s of files that I would like to rename in a specific manner according to a correlated list. Rather than repeating the same cmdlets, as below, I would like to point the cmdlet to a couple of list files (below) containing the old and new names, say old.txt and new.txt. How do I do this using PowerShell?

**Example:**

```psh
Rename-Item -Path "E:\MyFolder\old1.pdf" -NewName new1.pdf
Rename-Item -Path "E:\MyFolder\old2.tif" -NewName new2.pdf
Rename-Item -Path "E:\MyFolder\old3.pdf" -NewName new3.pdf
```

**List Files:**

***old.txt =***

```
old1.pdf
old2.tif
old3.pdf
```

***new.txt =***

```
new1.pdf
new2.tif
new3.pdf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid misalignment between the entries in `old.txt` and `new.txt` files, you could also put the files into a CSV file:

## *renames.csv =*

```
old1.pdf,new1.pdf
old2.tif,new2.tif
old3.pdf,new3.pdf
```

Now you can use `Import-Csv` to import your "translation sets":

```psh
$Renames = Import-Csv '.\renames.csv' -Header "OldName","NewName"

foreach($File in $Renames) {
    Rename-Item $File.OldName $File.NewName
}
```

Comment: I like this and the answer above. Not sure which should get the green check - perhaps the crowd will point it out. Thx

Answer (score 5):

Simply read your two files into two lists and process them like this:

```psh
$old = Get-Content 'old.txt'
$new = Get-Content 'new.txt'

Set-Location '$:\MyFolder'

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $old.Count; $i++) {
  Rename-Item $old[$i] $new[$i]
}
```

Comment: A bit of explanation: Get-Content reads a file into a collection of strings, each of which is one line of the file. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx

Answer (score 2):

So just for yucks, here is the one-liner version.  It does depend on you being in the C:\MyFolder dir when you run it but that could easily be changed to a variable:

```
Get-Content new.txt -PipelineVariable NewName | 
    Foreach {$oldNames = Get-Content old.txt;$i=0} {Get-ChildItem $oldNames[$i++]} | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {$NewName} -WhatIf
```