# powershell Copying files into new directories - best way

Tags: powershell, copy-paste, file-rename

I'm using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012741/how-to-rename-files-using-a-list-file) to try to copy files to a new location using a .csv list where OldName is the current file name and NewName is the new name including filepath. 
What is the best way to force the script to generate a new folder according to the new path?

For example:

```
OldName    NewName
A.pdf      C:\NewFolder\Anew.pdf
```

This is my script

```
$Copies = Import-Csv '.\copies.csv' -Header "OldName","NewName"

foreach($File in $Copies) {
    New-Item -Force $File.NewName -Type File
    Copy-Item $File.OldName $File.NewName
}
```

But this overwrites any files that stay in the same folder before they get copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line where you create the directory:

```
New-Item -Force $File.NewName -Type File
```

With this:

```
$NewDir = ($File.NewName -as [System.IO.FileInfo]).DirectoryName
If (-not (Test-Path -Path $NewDir)) {
   New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $NewDir -Force | Out-Null
}
```